# Opening a new browser tab from rails action in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

so i have a Exam controller. Now the the file for it has a jqgrid (index.html.erb )on it. One clicks on the grid row and i have set upped the javascript for handling the event.
it looks like

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
function handleSelection(id) {
    <%=  
    remote_function :url => render_exam_exams_path,:with => "'id='+id" 
    %>
}
</script>
```

now the the method i was just testing as follows

```
def render_exam
    @exams = Exam.find(params[:id])
    #either
    #redirect_to home_index_path
    #or open this in new browser tab        
    #render :action => "render_exam"
end
```

and I have a view called render_exam as well. Now i have checked the server logs and all, everything works fine even the render_exam is generated as i could see that in chrome developer plugin. Now the problem is i want either

1. the controller action render_exam to open up a new tab and render render_exam view as it seems to be happening remotely (generating render_exam view and all)without changing the jqgrid page. But I couldn't find a way to open up a new browser tab to render the render_exam action view from the render_exam action itself rather than happening behind the scene.
   or
2. have the jqGrid (or index view) page redirected to the render_exam view. Now the problem here was the redirect_to action doesn't work in the view as it is supposed to be controller method. So i can't say.

---

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
function handleSelection(id) {
    <%= redirect_to :action => render_exam_exams_path, :with => "'id='+id"  %>
}
</script>
```

otherwise the problem would have been solved.
Any help is appreciated 
thanks

Comment: I need to do the same. Did you work out a way to open new tab from a rails controller?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't redirect and render in the same action since there's only one response per action. Second opening a new tab is a client side feature (controlled by your browser), you need to use something like ""target=_blank in your link which will open a new browser which in turn will request a page (render_exam_exams_path in your case) from the server.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, I mean I want the controller action render_exam to open up a new tab and render it's action. as the even was handled and action was sent render_exam remotely from the index page of the same Exam controller. Or if not least redirect user to view of render_exam on click which is what it is not doing right now as again the action was sent remotely from the handled event.I can't use target=_blank as the it was an click on the jqgrid row which will be handled by the javascript making the remote call.

Comment: what is the point of 'making the javascript call remotely' if your goal is to render the result in a new window anyways? that's what target=_blank does - it does not change the current page (same goal as making the javascript call remotely), but instead creates a new window with the desired request response, just as you want. maybe we're not understanding your goal?